# How can i keep red color on input text when page is reload/ jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, events, keypress, page-refresh

Is it possible to keep the red color input text(i.e. when the email is wrong) after page reload/refresh/pressed f5?
The problem is that, when i press f5 or refresh page, the input text color changes from red to it default black color.
Will be glad if someone show me appropriate code.
Tnx in advance!

This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var form=$("#form");
    var email=$("#email");
    var emailVal="неправилен email адрес";

form.submit(function(){
     if(validateEmail()) {return true;}
     else{return false;};
                        });

email.keyup(function(){
     var a=$("#email").val();
     var match_e=/^[A-Za-z0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9_.-]+[A-Za-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9.-]+  [A-Za-z0-9]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/;

  if(match_e.test(a)){email.css('color','#000');}});

function validateEmail(){
     var a=$("#email").val();
     var match_e=/^[A-Za-z0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9_.-]+[A-Za-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9.-]+[A-Za-z0-9]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/;

   if(match_e.test(a)){ 
        email.css('color','#000');
        return true;
  }else{
        email.val(emailVal).css('color','red');
        return false;}
}
});
```

Or there is one more proposal. May be better choice is on refreshing to return  its initial value text, something like value="email", and removing wrong message.
Both- keeping red text, or removing it when page refreshed will be acceptable for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Note:*** For this thing to happen you should be pretty sure that while reloading, the value of your text persists this means that you have to send the value from the server.

Now for validation 
Use [validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

```
<script src="dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $(window).load(function () {
            $('#your_form_id').valid();
        });
    });
</script>
<style>
    .error{
        color:red;
    }
</style>
```

**<form id='your_form_id'>** 
`<input name='txt' id='txt' class='email' value='YOUR DEFAULT VALUE'></input>`
     **</form>**

Comment: When i add this piece of your code:

$(window).load(function () {
            $('#email').val('EMAIL ADDRESS_');

    });


now everything is ok :). Tnx again

Answer (score 0):

you should call your validator function after the DOM is ready apart from form events.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you `validate` the page after rendering again ?
This can be done on the `ready` event. Read [this](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)